# Possible CUDA memory allocation bug?

Tags: c++, cuda

I'm attempting to create a 1D texture from a 5000 element array of `float4` values.

When I attempt to allocate the array, I get the following error:

`invalid argument`

That's literally all it says.

Here is the code:

```
cudaChannelFormatDesc channel = cudaCreateChannelDesc<float4>();
const std::size_t size = 5000;
float4 atmosphere[size];
cudaArray *p_atmosphere;
CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaMallocArray(&p_atmosphere, &channel, size * sizeof(float4));
```

What's going on here? Is my array too large? It doesn't seem like an outrageous amount of memory. Is there a better technique to bind a large array to a texture?

And here is my GPU information:

```
--- General information about Device 0
    Name: Quadro 2000
    Compute Capability: 2.1
    Clock Rate: 1251000 kHz
    Device Overlap: 
        Enabled
    Kernel Execution Timeout: 
        Enabled

--- Memory information for Device 0
    Total Global Memory: 1023 MB
    Total Constant Memory: 65536 K
    Max Memory Pitch: 2147483647
    Texture Alignment: 512

--- Multi Processor Information for Device 0
    Multiprocessor Count: 4
    Shared Memory Per MP: 49152 K
    Registers Per MP: 32768
    Threads in Warp: 32
    Max threads per block: 1024
    Max thread dimension: (1024, 1024, 1024)
    Max grid dimension: (65535, 65535, 65535)
```

Comment: You aren't passing a valid height to the call.

Comment: Not needed. http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__MEMORY_gf0689399573bd8a922351aae4d040349.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out.

The allocation should be

```
CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaMallocArray(&p_atmosphere, &channel, size);
```

instead of

```
CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaMallocArray(&p_atmosphere, &channel, size * sizeof(type));
```

Comment: `Maximum width for a 1D texture reference bound to a CUDA array` is limited to 65536 for compute capability 2.1.

Comment: Yep, that's the problem. I was attempting to allocate an array of size `sizeof(float4) * 5000` which is `80000` elements long. Thanks!